# VideoView not playing video from URL in Android

Tags: android

I tried so many links but for all links its show same error.But it's giving error "can't play this video".

My code is the following

```
public class VideoDemo extends Activity {

    private VideoView video;


    private static final String path ="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/6540154?v=3&amp;wmode=direct";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            try {
                // Start the MediaController
                MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                        VideoDemo.this);
                mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
                videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                videoview.setVideoURI(video);
                videoview.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because the url you are using is not the one of a video but of a media player that plays the video.

To play the actual video you first need to find the url.
One way to find it is to use [Livestreamer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/index.html).

Install it following the instructions and then you can run a command like this

```
livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/6540154 best --stream-url
```

The output of this command is a url that you can use in your VideoView.

Comment: Any other player which I can use instead of media player ?

Can you please provide output of this command  line

Comment: Not really because with the url you gave you are not trying to play a video but a flash file. Flash players are not suggested and hard to integrate.

Comment: Can you please provide output of this command line for the given URL.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Duiker101 for suggesting livestreamer... can you please suggest me a way to convert rtmp links so that i can play it in Video View?

Answer (score -1):

You have to permission in Your manifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

and below is code for play video from url -

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.start();
```